# Is a future continuous sentence with an embedded intention a valid construction?

Tags: grammaticality

The particular sentence that I have in mind is

> I will be going to go to the store once I'm no longer sick.

It seems off, but I think it's a valid construction. The sentence

> I will be intending to go to the store once I'm no longer sick.

carries the same meaning and doesn't sound odd, so I don't see any reason why the first construction should be considered incorrect. Is this a valid construction?

Comment: I think it would be more natural to say simply, “I'll go to the store once I'm no longer sick.”

Comment: "I'll be **going to go** type construction is often reduced to "I'll be **going to** (the store)" might explain why it sounds "odd" to you but the first sentence is grammatical nevertheless. "I will be intending to go to the store..." is verging on the absurd as snailboat pointed out. The future continuous in spoken English is used but it's just overly formal in this context. I'd use contractions and say: "I'll go to the store as soon as I'm feeling better".

Answer (score 3):

In both of your examples, you're expressing that your intent will change in the future.  In other words, you intend to change your intent.  This is rather odd semantically and is almost never what anyone intends to say.  Once you've changed your mind about what you'll do in the future, you've changed your mind **right now**.  It makes a lot more sense for people to describe their **current** intent.

Grammatically it's fine.  It's only semantically unusual and very nearly nonsensical.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I need then: a semantically peculiar sentence that's perfectly fine grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is more an elaboration on what sailboat offers; I feel that "I will be going to go" expresses that you, for lack of a better way of phrasing off the top of my head, will *intend to intend* to go to the store. In other words, you're speaking of a plan but expressing it in such a way that almost seems that the plan hasn't materialized yet.

However, I feel that its awkwardness to the ear can be nullified contextually. If you're speaking in regards to a specific time frame in which you will **not** be sick, then I believe you may find it to be less awkward.

It is both a strength and an idiosyncrasy of the English language to afford such options, but I'd err on the side of 'most conventional'.